# Error on saving to Pickle - TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to save the following to pickle but am getting the error saying my argument must be str, not bytes. I have looked at the pickle documentation and tried converting x and y to strings with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import pickle



df = {'Description':[100,200,300,400,500],'Level_1':[1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['Description','Level_1'])

print(df)

   Description  Level_1
0          100        1
1          200        2
2          300        3
3          400        4
4          500        5

x = df[['Description']]
y = df['Level_1']

nb = GaussianNB()
nb.fit(x,y)

open('level1_classifier.pk', 'wb')
with open ('level1_classifier.pk') as l1clf:
    pickle.dump(nb, l1clf)

Error Message:
 ``TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-89a76f30f361> in <module>
      6 #open('level1_classifier.pk', 'wb')
      7 with open ('level1_classifier.pk') as l1clf:
----> 8     pickle.dump(nb, l1clf)

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Here is the stack:                                                                                                       TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-89a76f30f361> in <module>
      6 #open('level1_classifier.pk', 'wb')
      7 with open ('level1_classifier.pk') as l1clf:
----> 8     pickle.dump(nb, l1clf)

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to debug without a proper stack trace, please add one.

That said, you are opening the pickle file for writing and then opening it for reading. This is unnecessary and probably what's failing here.

This:

```
open('level1_classifier.pk', 'wb')
with open ('level1_classifier.pk') as l1clf:
    pickle.dump(nb, l1clf)
```

Should probably be like this:

```
with open('level1_classifier.pk', 'wb') as l1clf:
    pickle.dump(nb, l1clf)
```

See [this guide](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-save-a-scikit-learn-classifier-to-disk-in-python) for more details

Comment: I have added that above. I tried it even without the first open statement and I got the same error message.

Comment: notice that you need to open the file for writing not for reading. `with open ('level1_classifier.pk') as l1clf:` needs to be `with open('level1_classifier.pk', 'wb') as l1clf:`

Comment: Found [this article](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-save-a-scikit-learn-classifier-to-disk-in-python) that might help

Comment: You're welcome! If this answered your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Done - I'm still new to Stack Overflow so still learning :-)